# why no typescript errors when refering to nonexistant onkeydown?

Tags: typescript

Here is my *entire* ts file:

```js
document.onkeydown=onkeydown
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowArbitraryExtensions":true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "lib": [
       "ES2021", "dom", "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
    
  },
  "lib": ["ES2021"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist","tmp"]
}
```

my question is: why doenst tsc emit any error even those `onkeydown` is not defined in the file.

Comment: @JaredSmith, I am not on devtool yes. just testing my code staticly for errors using tsc

Comment: deleted my earlier comment, misread your question. `window.onkeydown` is set to `null` by default and so `onkeydown` does exist in the global scope. Since you have `lib` set to include `dom` in your tsconfig, the compiler understands the implicit existence of that global.

Comment: i just deleted `dom` from my tsconfig and now i have many other other in the rest my project , for example, missing `Window`. is there a way to get error for `onkeydown` and not error for `window` ?

Comment: The short answer is "it depends". As VLAZ's answer suggests, turning on strict checking will give you what you want, but you may find that you get a lot more errors you weren't aware of by turning it on. If this is a web project, you should definitely include the DOM types. Leaving that out is for non-web Typescript files like node.js server or script files.

Comment: Yes, turning on `strictFunctionType` does give me the required error, but it also generates many errors in other places in my code. This time these errors are justified and fixing them will probably make my code more stable. I'll try to work with that option. I hope it will justify the effort. Thanks for that!

  It's strange how  the typescript authors chose to declare a global variable for `onkeydown` rather just a type

Comment: "It's strange how the typescript authors chose to declare a global variable" they didn't. Their types (including the global `window` type and all its properties) have to match what browser vendors already implement. Blame the DOM, not Typescript :D

Comment: looking at my copy of `lib.dom.d.ts` i see

`declare var onkeydown: ((this: Window, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any) | null;`

isnt that a variable defintion?

Comment: No, it's a type definition. The `declare` statement isn't part of Javascript syntax. There shouldn't be anything but type definitions in a .d.ts file.

Comment: My brain hurts just thinking about this. When looking at the expression `document.onkeydown=onkeydown` left side is a variable, but the right side is a type? How's that working?

Comment: No. That statement `document.onkeydown=onkeydown` is pure Javascript. The reason the Typescript typechecker doesn't complain is because `lib.dom.d.ts` defines all the types of the globally available stuff (window, document, etc) so when you include those type definitions the typechecker knows there is a global variable `onkeydown` created by the browser and so doesn't complain about the usage. That's what the `declare` you found does: it defines the *type* of that built-in global. You can write `ocument.onkeydown=onkeydown` as `ocument.onkeydown=window.onkeydown` and it means the same thing.

Comment: yes, that starting to make sense to me, thank  you so much for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

The `onkeydown` property is available on `window`, which makes it a global:

```js
console.log( typeof onkeydown );
console.log( window.onkeydown === onkeydown );
```

Adding `"dom"` to the [`lib` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) enables this behaviour as it adds the types for `window` and other browser-related objects to the compilation.

There is an additional reason this code will not have a compilation error: [`strictFunctionType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) is disabled. With it enabled (or alternatively [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) which includes that rule and other ones) there would be an error:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false#code/CYewxgrgtgpgdgFwHQjgaxgT1AdzgXlQ2xDwG4g)

This is because the signature of `window.onkeydown` is:

```typescript
(this: Window, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any
```

while the signature `document.onkeydown` is:

```typescript
(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any
```

Therefore the two will not match

Comment: You might want to also mention that this happens in part because OP has `lib` set to include `dom` in their tsconfig, without that this will error even without strict checking.

Comment: Yes, turning on `strictFunctionType` does give me the required error, but it also generates many errors in other places in my code. This time these errors are justified and fixing them will probably make my code more stable. I'll try to work with that option. I hope it will justify the effort. Thanks for that!

  It's strange how  the typescript authors chose to declare a global variable for `onkeydown` rather just a type

Comment: @yigal "*It's strange how the typescript authors chose to declare a global variable for onkeydown*" it's because that accurately reflects JS as you can see in the runnable example. *Not* doing that would mean that code like `location.href` or `alert()` or `console,log()` will not work. There are all global by virtue of being properties of `window`. It's the same with `onkeydown`.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I found a solution that might be clunky, but it does work for me. It seems like it's a problem with typescript. They have extra definitions for event handles that are completly not usefull for catching errors for missing handlers as described in the qeustion.

The definitions are located in a file called `lib.dom.d.ts`. here is an an example from that file

```js
declare var onkeydown: ((this: Window, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any) | null;
```

My solution is go to that file and comment out all those definitions. To do that, goto that file and replace all `declare var on` with `//declare var on`

The file is normally located Within your project in this directory:
`./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`

If you're using vscode, then there's another copy of this file That you need to change. This is the location in my system:
`C:\Users\yigal\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts`

Comment: I strongly recommend you not do this. Your package manager will almost certainly overwrite your changed files, and if you are working on a team you will have issues where your teammates see errors that you don't. "They have extra definitions for event handles" no, they define types for the *globally available event handlers that already exist in Javascript*. There isn't anything Typescript can do about how Javascript and the DOM already are: they have to type these things because they **already exist and to not do so would be a serious affront to the usability of the type checker**.

Comment: i agree with you. to explain it to myself, i opened up a console on an empty webpage and typed onkeydown . the console printed null. confirming that the global variable exists and its value is null. therefor typescript is correct, onkeydown is defined and its value id null